# Super classes and sub classes -- method use

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

so I'm new to learning objective-C and OOP in general. I've been watching some videos from Udemy and didn't really understand how sub classes worked. He created a cocoa touch class called "Vehicle" which is a subclass of "Viewcontroller". Now, does this mean that viewcontroller now has access to methods within "Vehicle"?

Next, he then created a sub class of "Vehicle" called "Civic". He created a method in Civic.m that does this:

```
-(void)test 
{
  self.make = @"Honda";
  self.model = @"Civic";
}
```

If I then did this in my viewcontroller.m file shouldn't it set model and make to Honda and Civic when I create an instance of that class?

```
vehicle *civic1 = [[vehicle alloc]init];

NSLog(@"print out the make and model: %@ and %@", civic1.make, 
civic1.model);
```

Instead, it's prints out null for both. Why is this?

Comment: You call for `[civic1 test];` is missing

Comment: I tried this before and gave me this error:
- No visible @interface for 'vehicle' declares the selector 'test'

Comment: From what you've said, I think you're trying to learn this stuff from a really bad example.  For example, a "Vehicle" almost certainly shouldn't be a type of view controller, and initializing properties inside a `test` method instead of `init` is just weird.

Comment: I did, but then it's trying to access that method from the Vehicle class, but I need to access the method of CIvic class which is a subclass of Vehicle.

@PhillipMills Sorry, Vehicle is a subclass of NSObject.

Comment: You Vehicle class must have the method declaration to be redefined by your subclass Civic, or you can cast to Civic and call your method, check the answer posted

Comment: You're understanding of subclasses seems backward.  A `Civic` is all things a `Vehicle` is, but more since it overrides `test`.  A `Vehicle` is all things a `UIViewController` is.

Comment: Right, I understand that.

My whole thing was really understanding the hierarchy of things. Check out my comment below to Marico's answer.

Comment: @MichaelBenton check my answer

Comment: @MichaelBenton OOP is a topic a bit hard to learn through the comment section.. feel free to message me on fb fb.com/mrpatrnogic if you have questions

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic will do! Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both attributes are nil because you are never calling the "test" function.

```
vehicle *civic1 = [[vehicle alloc]init];
//here the call
[civic1 test];
//
NSLog(@"print out the make and model: %@ and %@", civic1.make, 
civic1.model);
```

The next problem you have is that you are creating a Vehicle instance, not a Civic instance. As test is a method of Civic class you are not allowed to call that method.

Change your code so you create a Civic instead of a Vehicle.

Option1

```
vehicle *civic1 = [[civic alloc]init]; //pointer to a vehicle.. but creating a civic
//here the call
[((civic*)civic1) test]; //typecast the vehicle pointer to use it as the civic it is
//
```

Option2

```
civic *civic1 = [[civic alloc]init]; //civic pointer, and creating a civic
//here the call
[civic1 test];
//
```

Comment: So, this is more a conceptual question. Lets say I'm creating an app that lets you buy a car. In a small portion of the app you have all the car makes, models, etc. Is it better to create super class called Car and then create subclasses of that class for each make, and then have subclasses of models? I'm trying to understand the hierarchy of things in this.

Comment: Please mark if this was the correct answer to your question.
If the models have different implementations, it is correct to create a class Car and sublass it.. If they have all the same implementation its just fine to have a Car class.. and just set the model as a property of the car.. no need to subclass it

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic i think this is not the right approach because if you have some other models subclassing vehicle then by your answer you need to check its types and cast for method call?

Comment: Yes as a general rule of thumb you go from general to specific and keep in mind there should be a "is a" relationship between super class and subclass like you would have noticed that ViewController is a subclass of UIViewController, so we can say that ViewController "is a " UIViewController. and likewise Honda "is a" Car. Hope it helps

Comment: @ReinierMelian " If the models have different implementations" .. if they have all the same implementation then there is no need to subclass

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic but this question is about of OOP and polymorphism and hierarchy, or a Iam wrong?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Yes you are right.. from OOP perspective.. its ok to subclass and do polymorphism. My point is "does he really need to use polymorphism?".. what if all his subclasses do the same.. and there is no need to subclass the Car?.. the app is meant to help you buy a car.. I honestly think there is no need to subclass. thats why i said  "If they have all the same implementation " in previous comment.

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic first line of the asker question `so I'm new to learning objective-C and OOP in general`.... i think this question is about learning hierarchy and polymorphism more than an specific issue

Comment: I agree, it's more conceptual help that I needed and then how to access certain methods in subclasses. Regardless of the Car App thing, which is the correct way to access a method of a subclass from viewcontroller? Option 1?

Answer (score 0):

You need declare the `test` method in your `Vehicle` class. Your `Vehicle` class must have the method declaration to be redefined by your subclass `Civic`, then polymorphism should work. If you have other subclasses, the test method will be called to the right class without casting and checking for types, then this code:

```
vehicle *civic1 = [[vehicle alloc]init];
[civic1 test];
NSLog(@"print out the make and model: %@ and %@", civic1.make, 
civic1.model);
```

should work.

Hope this helps.